# Local cache on a client machine of data located on a storage server

Tags: windows-7, storage, network-attached-storage, cache

So I've got a storage server where I put most of my data. I work on a laptop. When I try to access some files from my server, this is slower than from my laptop disk, which is normal. But I often retrieve the same files and have to wait each time. That could be fixed if I could set up a local cache on my laptop. Is there software that would allow me to do such a thing?

Also, I use windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you connect to the server, or more specific what protocol you use, you could use the **offline files** feature in Windows 7. Windows 7 has a thing called sync center, where you can enable this.

Windows servers and Samba servers both support this.

Answer (score 0):

[Offline files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Understanding-offline-files) has been a component of Windows since Windows 2000.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [openafs](http://www.openafs.org/) client for MSWindows (along with lots opf other operating systems) which supports proper cluster level file replication.